# Объединение множеств

Tags: множества, char, массивы, c++

Задание: Найти множество E содержащее все строчные русские буквы из А и B, но не являющиеся общими для множеств С и D. нужно все это дело сделать через массив битов. Так понимаю что мне из char нужно будет перевести в двоичный код. Идея только одна: сделать какой-то массив
char X[] и заполнить его строчными русскими буквами, потом вводить с клавиатуры каждое множество A, B, C, D, и проверять каждый элемент отдельного множества с X и если совпадают то iый элемент множества ставить в "true", это, конечно, не совсем рационально, но программирование изучаю недавно, поэтому других идей, к сожалению, нет.
Вопрос в другом, как потом получить множество E? есть ли какие то соответствующие операторы ? уровень программирования, повторюсь, начальный, поэтому не предлагайте, пожалуйста слишком "заумные" варианты).

Comment: Вы [уже задавали](http://hashcode.ru/questions/176885/c-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) этот вопрос. Попробуйте разбить его на части, что ли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@skies](/users/7836/skies), с какой кодировкой русского (однобайтная, utf-8 или UCS) работаете?

В любом случае, русские строчные буквы можно пронумеровать 0..32 (например `а` - 0, `б` - 1, ... `я` - 31, `ё` - 32) и использовать 64-бит целое (unsigned long long или uint64_t) для представления этого множества.

Тогда для добавления буквы (ее номера n) в множество A пишете:

```
A |= (1<<n);
```

для исключения буквы из множества

```
A &= ~(1<<n);
```

для проверки есть ли буква в множестве (установлен ли бит) используете выражение

```
(A & (1<<n))
```

Объединение 2-х множеств (A и B)

```
AB = A | B;
CD = C | D;
```

Тогда буквы, которые есть в AB и которые отсутствуют в CD это

E = AB & ~CD;

Поясню. В CD в 1 установлены биты для каждой из букв, которые есть в C или D. Операция ~ инвертирует все биты. Операция & сбросит все биты в AB, для которых сброшены биты в CD, а остальные **оставит без изменения**.

IMHO все.